# Why I cannot add a navigationItem outlet from File Owner to Navigation Item?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uinavigationbar

I did this in a viewController

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.Share;
```

And that does it right.

However, I want to do this in xib instead.

I managed to put a Navigation Item item in XIB and I want that to be the navigationItem of the viewController.

Yet I can't do that.

While I can point the "view" outlet from the viewController, I can't point navigationItem

Actually how to add a rightBarButtonItem through XIB?

Who "owns" that rightBarButtonItem anyway? The navigationController or the viewController under it? How exactly does that interact? There is this navigationBar item in object library but I am not really sure how to use it.

Comment: I can see references around the web to people setting the navigationItem outlet - but I am having the same issue as you, no outlet on files owner.  As a temp workaround I'm creating my own outlet and programmatically assigning, but it's very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a bar button in the coding like IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem * saveButton;

Then you have to take a bar button in the xib file and bind this button with that and in coding you can directly write self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;

Comment: The whole point of this question is so I do not have to do self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.Share; in viewDidLoad. Please try again Sameer. +1 for effort.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is correct. Basically I can add navigationItem under the viewController, and viewController.navigationItem automatically point to that navigationItem.

That's it. No outlet is necessary. So it's different than view outlet.

I'll select this as the right answer unless someone told me differently.

Also, having a navigationItem there will prevent the title of the navigation bar to be your viewController title.

You have to do self.navigationItem.title=self.title in viewDidLoad, and I feel that I must have done something wrong here.